# How to I get mcomix to remember my rotation settings?

Tags: lubuntu, configuration

I'm using a fresh install of Lubuntu 14.10, and have installed Mcomix version 1.00-1
 from the universe repositories.

I'm trying to rotate the whole comic, so that I can read it by turning my laptop sideways. However, when I rotate one page, it only rotates that page, not the whole comic. When I flip to the next page, it is back to its standard orientation.

What do I need to do so that mcomix will remember my rotation preferences? I think the term is persistence...

I'm pretty sure this worked on my older laptop, but I don't have it in front of me to check.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. After hitting <kbd>r</kbd> to rotate the page, I hit <kbd>k</kbd>, which is the keyboard shortcut for "keep transformation". Once I did this, the rotation was saved throughout the rest of the comic book.

In version 1.00-1, this option is not found in the **Preferences** menu. I think it was found in the Preferences menu in earlier versions of mcomix.

I found this option by going through `~/.config/mcomix/keybindings-gtk.rc`